# How to duplicate an image into a new PSD and keep the original title (name) of the image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs4

Hey I'm trying to duplicate an image that has been titled (a specific name) into a PSD and keep the image title (a specific name).

I have a few titled images that need to be a certain size and effects. So I created a PSD with all the effects and the size I need. I want to duplicate the titled images into the PSD and then save as a new image but with the original title of each image.

I know I can do this the long way and copy and paste each title for each image but is there faster way to make the title of the image duplicate with the image it self into the new psd?

To be specific I use CS4 and I know how to duplicate images or drag them into a PSD. But when I do so the image (layer) renames its self background or layer and a number.

When I open the image in CS4 it has the title it was given in the topbar but the image layer is called layer0. When I right click duplicate on it I can name the image (layer) and choose the destination.

How can I make the title of that image appear in the layer name section automatically. So when it is duplicated to the new PSD that layer has the name that it was given when it was a single image.

Appreciate the help. 
Best Regards

Comment: I guess Photoshop is not really cares about file names and not move them to layer names.. and vice versa

Comment: @Vnovak seems that way but I am no expert at PhotoShop. So I'm sure if I knew better PhotoShop put something in place to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Photoshop CS6+ you can use `File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack`

No clue if that's possible in CS4.

Comment: I can verify that it exists in CS5 -- and [apparently it's been around since CS3](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/542264?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: If you drag a psd file into photoshop, it will keep the original file name as the layer. Couldn't you then just export the layers without a prefix?

Comment: @Scott Hey yes this worked but whats happening is that its creating a new PSD, then I still have to duplicate them into the PSD I need. How can I add them to the PSD I need or choose the destination path?

Comment: @GoofyMonkey Yes but I need to keep the orginal name of each image that I drag into a PSD not the PSD into Photoshop.

Comment: @user25889 I don't understand.. load the files into a stack.... select all the layers of your stack, Group them... drag to whatever psd you need them in.

Comment: @UserI25889  don't think it matters if it's a psd or a JPEG file. If you drag it into a photoshop file it PS should create a smart object with the original file name as the name for the new object. But if it doesn't work for your workflow I'm not sure how to get what you are looking for.

Comment: @Scott Hey yes this is exactly what I did. I never used that script so I thought it will stack the images into my PSD and not in a new one. But I did as you said and it works great really appreciate the help. Best Regards

Comment: @GoofyMonkey Hey thanks for the response I used @ Scott's technique and it worked for me its an extra step than I planned on but did exactly what I needed. Really saved me some time as I need to do this to 500 + pics. Thanks to everyone for the help much appreciated.